# Webpack: Using Bundle.js, "React is not defined"

Tags: javascript, jquery, node.js, webpack

I've used Webpack to bundle all my npm modules. Here's my webpack.config.js:

```
"use strict";

module.exports = {
    entry: './main.js',
    output: { path: __dirname, filename: 'bundle.js' },

    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /.js?$/,
                loader: 'babel-loader',
                exclude: /node_modules/,
                query: {
                    presets: ['es2015', 'react']
                }
            },
            {test: /\.json$/, loader: "json"},
        ]
    },
};
```

Here's the main.js I refer to. As you can see, I try to import React, React-dom, fixed-data-table, chartjs, jquery and visjs.

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from 'fixed-data-table';
import Chart from 'chartjs';
import jquery from 'jquery';
import vis from 'vis';
```

All is good, and I remoce the react, chartjs, jquery etc. src from my index.html and just refer to the newly created bundle.js altogether.

In my functional .js file where content is derived from, and my react classes are, I add the following to the beginning(where I assume the error stems from)

```
import React from './bundle';
import ReactDOM from './bundle';
import {Table, Column, Cell} from './bundle';
import Chart from './bundle';
import vis from './bundle';
```

This results in my browser dev tools giving me the error: Uncaught Referenceerror: React is not defined.

Where did I go wrong in the bundling process? I'm assuming the bundling went fine since there were no errors. But how do I import, for example, React in another .js file properly?

Here's my package.json:

```
{
  "name": "test",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "main.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-core": "^6.3.17",
    "babel-loader": "^6.2.0",
    "babel-preset-es2015": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-preset-react": "^6.3.13",
    "babel-runtime": "^6.3.19",
    "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
    "webpack": "^1.12.9"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "chartjs": "^0.3.24",
    "fixed-data-table": "^0.6.0",
    "react": "^0.14.3",
    "react-dom": "^0.14.3",
    "vis": "^4.17.0"
  }
}
```

Comment: What does your package.json look like? Double check you've actually installed the react dependencies.

Comment: I've edited to include the package.json.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Webpack will start from `'./main.js'` and read `import` statement to determine the modules need to bundle.

[webpack concept](https://webpack.js.org/concepts/)

**Update:**

Since the library already in bundle.js, your files should look like this :

Index.html(do not include any library already import in .js file you write)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title></title>
</head>
<body>
    <div id="app"></div>
    <script src="bundle.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

main.js :

```
import React from 'react';
....
```

Comment: Sorry if I explained myself poorly; I already added the bundle.js in my index.html, and then removed the "old" sources(like react, react-dom, visjs and chartjs), as these should now be in the bundle.js instead.

Comment: in this case you don't need any import.

Comment: Not if I make another .js file where I create reactclasses? Right now this file says "missing import statement" when I call react, so something definitely went wrong in the process then. Perhaps my approach with the Main.js is wrong..? Just importing them there? Should it be different?

Comment: Do not remove your source like node_modules/react, and import it in every new js file is the correct way.

Comment: node_modules have not been touched, they are still there. But isn't the idea that you can bundle all your node_modules into one JS file, and then import from there?

Comment: No, the idea is everytime webpack will read your file and determine how to bundle by import statement, then create new bundle.js

Comment: Ok, I guess the concept doesn't mean much to me, I don't see the benefit if I can't bundle react libraries and import them.. It sounds like I have to anyway have react-min.js as a source in my index.html this way..?

Comment: Since the library already bundle in bundle.js, you don't need to include any other than `bundle.js` in your `index.html`

Comment: That I understand. But if I make another .js file to include my React classes, they don't recognize the React functions at all, so something seems off.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/131660/discussion-between-andy-chen-and-cbll).

Answer (score 3):

You can't import from 'bundle.js', because it is compiled to ES5 and ES5 don't support modules (imports and exports).

Properly way to import React to another js is via import

```
import React from 'react'
```

You can find more info about Modules at:
https://www.sitepoint.com/understanding-es6-modules/

Comment: So in my react file, I should just do `import React from 'react'` and it should work..? Isn't that what I already tried - i'm not too sure :) If I can't bundle everything with webpack and use it from there, what's the point exactly?

Comment: I think that you didn't include bundle.js properly. Could you provide link to repo?

Comment: I can't show the repo unfortunately. I simply replaced the way I imported react previously and then referred to the bundle.js in the html head. As   `<script src="bundle.js"></script>`